# Laravel class 'UserRole' not found

Tags: php, laravel, model

Hi i am trying to use a model for a test but i get **Class 'App\UserRole' not found** this is my controller where i am calling it

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UserRole;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $role = UserRole::get();
        die(var_dump($role));
    }
}
```

and this is my model

```
<?php

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class UserRole extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'role';
    public $primaryKey = 'id_role';
    public $timestamps = false;

    const ADMIN = 1;
    const OPERATOR = 2;
    const CUSTOMER = 3;
}
```

I dont know what im missing, i tried to do the same with User model and it works perfect, also my table is created and populated.

Comment: well you didn't define that class to exist in any namespace so that class is not `App\UserRole`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a namespace to your model

```
namespace App;
```

Should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class UserRole extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'role';
    public $primaryKey = 'id_role';
    public $timestamps = false;

    const ADMIN = 1;
    const OPERATOR = 2;
    const CUSTOMER = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your model

```
namespace App;
```

Comment: that would make the FQCN `App\UserRole\UserRole`